# What does the phrase "There's a little bit of an edge" mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm listening to [this](http://www.se-radio.net/2014/08/episode-208-randy-shoup-on-hiring-in-the-software-industry/) podcast and I hear the following phrase at around 13:45.

> **There's a little bit of an edge** to work in a company where you make
>   games.

I can guess only guess it means: *It is a priviledge* or something like that. I've searched the phrase in google but didn't find anything. Could anyone please elaborate on the actual meaning of this phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It means if you have an [**edge over someone**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/edge), think of yourself as **a
>   little sharper** because you have **the advantage**.

(TFD)
 - 3. A margin of superiority; an advantage: a *slight edge* over the opposition.

> There's a **little bit of an edge** to work in a company where you make
>   games asserts that such a company will give you the **competitive
>   edge** over others.

- Similarly, if your company is on the **cutting edge** of gaming technology, it is the industry leader.

Answer (score 3):

In the supplied context, it sounds as though the word **edge** is being used in the sense outlined in definition 2.1 [on OxfordDictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/edge):

> [IN SINGULAR] An intense, sharp, or striking quality:
>
> *a flamenco singer brings a primitive edge to the music*
>
> *there was an edge of menace in his voice*

The speaker in your podcast is likely trying to convey that working for a games company is exciting, intense, dynamic and possibly high-paced in respect to companies in other sectors.

Answer (score 2):

It might mean:

[noun

3.
 
a quality or factor which gives superiority over close rivals.

*"his cars have the edge over his rivals'"*

synonyms:   advantage, lead, head, head start, trump card, the whip hand . . . .
antonyms:   disadvantage](https://www.google/search?q=define+edge&oq=define+edge)

--Google's dictionary

So, in the context you give, perhaps superior because fun or interesting, or maybe advantageous in increasing one's value on the job market in certain areas.

Comment: 568ml's answer is also possible, as is Brian Hitchcock's. Maybe the intended meaning can be discerned from what was said before or after the quoted sentence.

Answer (score 2):

To have an "edge" is to have a slight advantage. See def 2(d) in this:

http://i.word.com/idictionary/edge

I'm guessing the speaker considers it useful for career advancement to be able to say one has worked at a game company.

But it is odd he said "to work" rather than "to working".  So it's possible he might have meant that the work itself had an "edge" to it; that it is edgy, or cutting-edge, meaning at the forefront of the art.  See definition 2 here:
http://i.word.com/idictionary/cutting-edge